# How to slow page loading inside to div?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am using jquery to fadein div which i animate to get bigger and then i load php file in it using ajax. Problem is that ajax loads php file before div is visible and animated big enough. Therefore php page shows onscreen and after that div loads under it. How can i slow down php page loading or make it visible after div is visible? Toppi and links are variables. Toppi contains position of div and links php page name.

Here is the code i use:

```
$("#riv1").css("top", + toppi);
$("#riv1").fadeIn();
$("#riv1").animate({height:'600px',opacity:'0.4'},"fast");
$("#riv1").animate({width:'850px',opacity:'0.8'},"fast");
$("#riv1").animate({opacity:'1.0'}, 500);

if (links != '') {
    $.ajax({
        async:false,
        url: links,
        cache: false
    }).done(function( html ) {
        $("#riv1").html(html);
    });
}
```

I have tried

```
$("#riv1").delay(2000).html(html);
```

but this does not help.

Comment: Have your fade in animation on complete trigger the ajax call ratehr than doing the ajax request on page loading.

Comment: `$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#riv1").delay(2000).fadeIn(500);
});` use this

Comment: async:false will stuck the browser

Comment: `jQuery.animate` allows you to pass it an `onComplete` function. http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: If you use visibility property instead of display, you can fade that property without affecting page layout

Comment: I have used async: True but had no difference between false / true in this case. But i will leave it as true when done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#riv1").css("top", + toppi);
$("#riv1").fadeIn();
$("#riv1").animate({height:'600px',opacity:'0.4'},"fast");
$("#riv1").animate({width:'850px',opacity:'0.8'},"fast");
$("#riv1").animate({opacity:'1.0'}, 500,function(){
//calling ajax after animation completed 
   if (links != '') {
   $.ajax({
      async:false,
      url: links,
      cache: false
   }).done(function( html ) {
      $("#riv1").html(html);
  });
}
});
```

try making a ajax call once the final animation is completed

Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 1):

Try to put the ajax code in a callback function of fadeIn():

```
$("#riv1").css("top", + toppi);
$("#riv1").fadeIn("slow",function(){
    if (links != '') {
        $.ajax({
            async:false,
            url: links,
            cache: false
        }).done(function( html ) {
            $("#riv1").html(html);
        });
    }
});
$("#riv1").animate({height:'600px',opacity:'0.4'},"fast");
$("#riv1").animate({width:'850px',opacity:'0.8'},"fast");
$("#riv1").animate({opacity:'1.0'}, 500);
```

the ajax function will be called only when the fadeIn has been finished.

Answer (score 0):

You can show the loading image before jquery ajax request by using the function

**beforeSend** and can hide the loading image on success like below

```
    $.ajax({
    beforeSend:function(){
    //you logic to add the loading image inside the div
    }
    async:false,
    url: links,
    cache: false
    }).done(function( html ) {
              //Hide the images or replace the div with new content
        $("#riv1").html(html);
  });
```

Comment: Thank you. I have used loading image before. :)